# Precisamos da tag [src]?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

Eu nem entendi o porque desta tag, atualmente ela tem 15 perguntas, e também não tem recomendações nem wiki de tag, mas queria entender melhor.

Precisamos dessa tag [src](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/src)? Eu não sou muito entendedor das tags, mas ela não seria meio inútil?

Comment: É, bem inútil. Se eu tivesse uma ferramenta pra remover tags em lote eu faria isso agora. Não tendo, acho melhor isso ser feito num horário de menos movimento no site.

Comment: Nem tags "href", "onclick", "data", raramente serão úteis, as tags html e html5 cobrem perfeitamente perguntas sobre elas :)

Comment: Concordo com o @bfavaretto, esse tipo de limpeza é bom fazer em um horário menos movimentado, como fins de semana ou mais a noite, por volta de umas 9-10 horas q o site da uma reduzida no movimento.

Comment: Dúvida rápida pra aproveitar a leva: a gente precisa da tag [tag-específica](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag-espec%C3%ADfica)?

Comment: @Renan é do meta? Acho que sim, ela é útil aqui. Se for no principal, utilidade 0 :p

Comment: @Renan A intenção e separar discussões genéricas sobre tags de discussões como esta aqui. Mas é questionável mesmo :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não precisamos. O pessoal já se encarregou de removê-la de algumas perguntas e eu removi das últimas 5 perguntas.

Logo o sistema deve eliminar a *tag*.